# what is u64.l and u64.h?

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio

In Linux, dmidecode source code:

https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/master/dmidecode.c#L273

I see this:

```
static void dmi_print_memory_size(u64 code, int shift)
{
 ...

split[0] = code.l & 0x3FFUL;
split[1] = (code.l >> 10) & 0x3FFUL;
split[2] = (code.l >> 20) & 0x3FFUL;
split[3] = ((code.h << 2) & 0x3FCUL) | (code.l >> 30);
split[4] = (code.h >> 8) & 0x3FFUL;
split[5] = (code.h >> 18) & 0x3FFUL;
split[6] = code.h >> 28;
```

'code' is a u64 variable, why it has member .l and .h? and what are they for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The u64 type is defined in `types.h`:

```
#ifdef BIGENDIAN
typedef struct {
    u32 h;
    u32 l;
} u64;
#else
typedef struct {
    u32 l;
    u32 h;
} u64;
#endif
```

So it appears that the `.l` and `.h` members represent the "low" and "high" 32 bits of a 64-bit number.

Comment: in visual studio, I can't #include <types.h>